# Inline styles in react doesnt work in print mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

`<div styleName="item" key={index} style={{ backgroundColor: color[index] }}>`

So color[index] is hex color (ex. #ffffff).
I can see the proper color in web browsers but for some reason, that doesnt work in Print preview.

I tried to add 'blue' instead of color[index] and that worked in web browser but it didnt update the print preview.

I think inline styles dont work with print.
I need to generate the color dynamically so I cant just use one color in css file.

Is there anyone went through same problem?

In chrome :

[image: in Chrome]

In print preview mode:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to include this @media print property in your main css file:

```
@media print {
   body {
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
   }
}
```

There is also a checkbox in the chrome print settings that says "Background Graphics" that you may need to check.

[image]

Comment: Checking background graphics solved my problem. Thanks!